# Django migration to delete rows from database

Tags: django

How can I delete rows from a database table with some criteria via a migration script?
Do I need to manually write it or generate it? How to create the file?

Comment: Did you want to delete rows? not fields?

Comment: I think you want a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Answer (score 9):

You need to create an empty migration file:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_label> --empty
```

open the generated file and add a new operation:

```py
operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(delete_some_rows) # name_of_the_function_to_be_called_to_delete_rows
]
```

define the function in the migration file:

```py
def delete_some_rows(apps, scheme_editor):
    model = apps.get_model('app_label', 'model_name')
    model.objects.filter(...).delete()
```

and simply migrate.